# Implementation of DeepAr with AWS chime on React Native (Live streaming)

Tags: react-native, aws-chime-sdk, deepar

We need to implement DeepAr with AWS chime on React Native. Currently live stream with AWS chime is done but facing problem to integrate DeepAr for broadcasting. DeepAr only is integrated for liver side but couldnot sent that frame towards the AWS chime on the other end.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experience with DeepAR. But here is the things I suggest you to do.

1. Make sure video stream displaying in liver screen and stream broadcasted to chime are same.
2. Avoid multiple stream initialization because you will face hardware limitations on Apple devices.

You need to get a stream from DeepAR and pass it to chime.
OR
You can try a workaround, like an initialized stream for Chime SDK, and later on, attach it with DeepAR.